# Remove padding of NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I want to remove the space of a window in cocoa. I want it like the left one, but I can't find out how to do this.

[image]

Comment: Isn't that MAC so isn't it an `NSWindow` and not a `UIWindow`?

Comment: Yeah that is correct, sorry

Comment: How are you creating the `NSWindow`?

Comment: Have you tried changing the content border in the size inspector in IB for the window?

Comment: @Popeye it was an already existing project so I didn't create it

Comment: Have you made any attempt at trying to resolve this yourself then or did you come straight to SO and the question? If you have tried anything please share as we could just be sending you back to something you have already looked at.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the padding on the left and the right, you should specify `Full Size Content View`

[image]